# Introducing new symbols into Common-Lisp Function/Macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I want to define a functionality in common lisp which uses some words/symbols not known to lisp, for example having such a function/macro:

```
(my-func-or-macro lst key-word idx)
```

which returns items in the `lst` upto the `idx` if the `key-word` is **to** and from the `idx` to the end if the `key-word` is **from**.

So practically it should work like:

```
(my-func-or-macro '(1 2 3 4 5 6) from 3) => '(4 5 6)
```

and

```
(my-func-or-macro '(1 2 3 4 5 6) to 3) => '(1 2 3)
```

Since macros don't evaluate their arguments i think i should be using a macro which doesn't care about `from` and `to` (note i don't want to pass quoted args like `'from` `'to`).

Comment: Usually you would use functions with keyword arguments for that: :from and :to .

Comment: Don't forget to add the actual question.'I want ...'  is not a question.

Comment: What exactly are you wondering about? How to compare symbols in different packages?

Answer (score 2):

Since every argument to a function is evaluated before the function is executed, you need a symbol that evaluates to itself.

Such symbols are already part of the language: all symbols in the special `KEYWORD` package evaluate to themselves.  Symbols that are written with a leading colon, e. g. `:foo` are interned into that package.

Also part of the language are keyword arguments that use such keywords to identify parameters:

```
(defun my-func (list &key from)
  (subseq list from))

(my-func '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :from 3)
=> (3 4 5)
```

You can give default values to such parameters:

```
(defun my-func (list &key (from 0) (to (length list)))
  (subseq list from to))

(my-func '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :from 3)
=> (3 4 5)

(my-func '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :to 3)
=> (0 1 2)

(my-func '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :from 1 :to 4)
=> (1 2 3)
```

Keyword arguments can be given in any order:

```
(my-func '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :to 4 :from 1)
=> (1 2 3)
```